# Call undefined method from module

Tags: python

I have a module where I want to call a method not defined in that module. Is it possible?

```
#module
def foo():
    print bar()

#main
from foo import foo

def bar():
    return "Foo bar"

def main():
    foo.foo()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Python looks up undefined names in the same module a function is defined in.

You'll have to pass in a function reference instead:

```
def foo(func):
    print func()
```

then in main:

```
def main():
    foo.foo(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the function from one module to the other, but passing it as a callback is probably neater. It depends on the situation.

```
#module
def foo(bar):
    print bar()

#main
from foo import foo

def bar():
    return "Foo bar"

def main():
    foo(bar)
```